# Cumulative Mode in numpy

Tags: numpy, scipy

I'd like to efficiently calculate a cumulative mode along an axis in numpy.

e.g.

```
>>> arr = np.random.RandomState(3).randint(3, size = (2, 5))
>>> arr
array([[2, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 2, 1]])
>>> assert np.array_equal(cummode(arr, axis = 1), [[2,2,2,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1])
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?  I guess it can handle ties by returning the first number to achieve the given count.

Comment: My mistake, I've edited the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pure Python function that works on a list, or any iterable:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def cummode(alist):
    dd = defaultdict(int)
    mode = [(None,0)]
    for i in alist:
        dd[i] += 1
        if dd[i]>mode[-1][1]:
            newmode = (i,dd[i])
        else:
            newmode = mode[-1]
        mode.append(newmode)
    mode.pop(0)
    return mode, dd

mode,dd = cummode([0,1,3,6,1,2,3,3,2,1,10,0])
print(dd)
print(mode)
```

which for the test case, produces

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 3, 6: 1, 10: 1})
[(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3)]
```

A `detaultdict` is a clean fast way of accumulating values when you don't know all the keys before hand.  For small lists and arrays it probably beats a `numpy` based version, even with `weave`, simply because it does not incure the overhead of creating arrays.  But with large ones it probably will lag.  Plus I haven't generalized it to handle multiple values (rows).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's not fully general in that it doesn't work along any axis, but for now I've made a version that works using scipy-weave.

```
from scipy import weave

def cummode(x, axis = 1):

    assert x.ndim == 2 and axis == 1, 'Only implemented for a special case!'
    all_values, element_ids = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
    n_unique = len(all_values)
    element_ids = element_ids.reshape(x.shape)
    result = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype = int)
    counts = np.zeros(n_unique, dtype = int)
    code = """
    int n_samples = Nelement_ids[0];
    int n_events = Nelement_ids[1];
    for (int i=0; i<n_samples; i++){
        int maxcount = 0;
        int maxel = -1;

        for (int k=0; k<n_unique; k++)
            counts[k] = 0;

        for (int j=0; j<n_events; j++){
            int ix = i*n_events+j;
            int k = element_ids[ix];
            counts[k]+=1;
            if (counts[k] > maxcount){
                maxcount = counts[k];
                maxel = k;
            }
            result[ix]=maxel;
        }
    }
    """
    weave.inline(code, ['element_ids', 'result', 'n_unique', 'counts'], compiler = 'gcc')
    mode_values = all_values[result]
    return mode_values
```